# click() event not triggered for second round

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to bind click function on the anchor tab with select class. I did it with the below code. It is working fine when I click for the first time but after that when I click on the anchor again the attached event doesn't initiated. I don't know what is wrong.
This is my jquery code to attach click event to anchor tab .

```
$('a.select').click(function () {
    var data = subtitle_json;
    data = data[$(this).attr('aria-controls')][0];
    $('p#subtitle-saved-ad > span:nth-child(1)').html(data.ad_count + " " + data.ad_text);
});
```

this is my html Dom.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs-collapsed" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class=""> <a href="#71" aria-controls="71" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="select">
                Cars            </a>

    </li>
    <li role="presentation"> <a href="#260" aria-controls="260" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="select">
                Bicycles            </a>

    </li>
    <li id="lastTab" class="" style="display: block;"> <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
              More <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="collapsed">
            <li role="presentation"> <a href="#72" aria-controls="72" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="select">
                Bikes &amp; Scooters            </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please indent your code first as it is one of the main source of issue. I bet this HTML code doesn't pass through [W3C HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Hi i am interchanging anchor tag dom in more dropdown with first anchor tag i.e cars whenever the more dropdown anchor tag is clicked. is it made any change with click event binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically adding the same anchor, the clickfunction disappears with it. Instead, link it to the body and listen for that type of element:
Replace this:

```
$('a.select').click(function() {
```

for this:

```
$('body').on("click", "a.select", function() {
```

Comment: In fact is more or less the same. From jQuery .click() documentation, "This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler )"

Comment: @RMontes13 No it is not the same. This `.on()` has 3 parameters. The second one is the selector, which makes this working for dynamicly created html elements. And you bind it also to a parent element, in this case the `body`

Comment: Hi i am interchanging anchor tag dom in more dropdown with first anchor tag i.e cars whenever the more dropdown anchor tag is clicked. is it made any change with click event binding

Answer (score 0):

There is missing code in the js part.

```
 $('a.select').click(function() {
  alert('click');
 });
```

This will throw the alert each time you click on the element.
Provide more code or try to develop it from this point.

Answer (score 0):

What i can say is that there is nothing wrong with your onclick even. It would be better if you explained the functionality a bit. just add a console or alert in the even to check whether the code is working or not.

Answer (score -1):

Check this jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/f0avxhsk/

I just added `alert()` to check whether is triggering or not

It is triggering